# Is there any way to decrypt an encoded asset(Video) ,in azure media services , for performing Progressive Download?

Tags: azure-media-services, progressive-download

Is there any way to decrypt an encoded asset ,in azure media services, to download an encrpted asset using media services, for performing Progressive Download ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC, you can install and use http://aka.ms/amse to accomplish this. Simply select the Asset and 'Ctrl+X' will bring up the download menu. The source code (using our .NET APIs) is also available from the same link.